# Making @media queries more specific and more focused

Tags: css, wordpress

Hello: I am trying to have my CSS (wordpress) change on different devices (responsive).  I am using @media queries in my child theme css file.  But I am finding that my queries are "overlapping" for iPad and iPhone.

here is what I am using for iPad:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait)
```

and here is what I am using for iPhone:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px)
```

I have found that on my iPhone - it is using both of the styles within both the queries…

I also have a plugin I use called "mobile" which allows me to use "is_mobile" and "is_tablet" etc which are very helpful…

so what I am trying to do is ensure that my CSS only applies on a mobile phone, or only applies on a tablet, and it seems these media queries are not as reliable as I thought…

the mobile plugin works good in separating them out; but i cannot use PHP if statements in the "style.css" file

So here are my questions:

1. is there a better way to write the two @media queries so they more clearly only work on the devices that I want?

thanks so much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use for it to change css depending on the width of the screen. Hope it helps.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

body
{
    margin:0px;
}
#wrapper
{
    min-width: 0px;
    width:auto;
}
#content
{
    margin-left: 0px;
}
#nav
{
    float:none;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
#nav ul
{
    text-align: center;
}
#nav li
{
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0.75em;
    padding-right: 0.75em;
}
footer
{
    margin-left: 0;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
body
{
    margin: 0px;
}
label
{
    float: none;
    text-align: left;
}
#wrapper
{
    width: auto;
    min-width: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#content
{
    padding-top: 0.1em;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
h1
{
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 0.3em;
}
#nav ul
{
    padding: 0px;
}
#nav li
{
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #330000;
}
#nav
{
    display: block;
}
#content img
{
    float: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0.1em;
}
#mobile
{
    display: inline;
}
#desktop
{
    display: none;
}
}
```

Comment: thanks, looks like you removed the min width things and so I will see if that helps; will let you know...

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}
/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}
/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}
/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```